# How can I get the explanation borders with pmatrix?

Tags: matrices

I have asked this question in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10945834#10945834). How can I add the explanation borders to the below matrix?

```
\begin{align*} 
C_{D_{1\succ 2}, \mathrm{increasing}}    &= \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 1   &   -1  &   1 & -1  &   1   &   -1 &    1 & -1  \\ \end{pmatrix}}_{1\times 8\text{ matrix}}  \\ 
A_{D_{1\succ 2}, \mathrm{increasing}}    &= 
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 
1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   \\ 
0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   \\ 
1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   \\ 
0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   \\ 
1   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\ 
1   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\ 
0   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   1   \\ 
\end{pmatrix}}_{7\times 8 \text{ matrix}}. 
\end{align*}
```

I want this kind of $p_1, p_2, ...$ borders to the matrix above. I have been able to add them with blockarray and block [here](http://pastebin.com/BC6uwvnt) but now I need to add them to the existing pmatrix data-structure. How can I get it with the pmatrix?

[image]

Comment: Consider the `kbordermatrix` package: http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf (you may need to get the `.sty` file yourself: http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/generic)/misc/kbordermatrix.sty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `kbordermatrix` package which is for some reason not CTAN but you can download it from http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml and there is a short documentation there too. Just save the `.sty` file to the same folder with your actual document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,kbordematrix}


\begin{document}

% Change the default brackets to parentheses
\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}
\[
\underbrace{\kbordermatrix{
    & t_1& t_2  &\cdots & t_n & \cdots & t_h &\cdots & t_{2^n}\\
p_1 &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   \\ 
p_2 &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   \\ 
p_3 &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   \\ 
p_4 &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   \\ \hline
p_5 &   1   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\ 
p_6 &   1   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\ 
p_7 &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   1   \\ 
}}_{7\times 8 \text{ matrix}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know whether there is any easy way to get the underbrace only under the matrix not under the explanation column $p_1,p_2,...,p_7$?

Comment: @hhh You can use `\cline{2-12}` starting from the second column

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry but I don't understand which one you are referring to. So, I've added both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray,multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
I_{D_{1\succ 2}, \mathrm{increasing}} &= \{53, 54, 57, 58, 69, 70, 73, 74\}_{\mathrm{DEC}} \\
C_{D_{1\succ 2}, \mathrm{increasing}} &= \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ \end{pmatrix}}_{1\times 8\text{ matrix}} \\
A_{D_{1\succ 2}, \mathrm{increasing}} &=
\underbrace{\begin{blockarray}{ccccccccc}
\begin{block}{c(cccccccc)}
p_1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
p_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
p_3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
p_4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
p_5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
p_6 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
p_7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}}_{7\times 8 \text{ matrix}}.
\end{align*}


\[
A=
  \underbrace{\begin{blockarray}{ccc|cccc|c|cccc}
    & t_1& t_2 & ... & ... & ... & ... & t_n & ... & t_h & ... & t_{2^n} \\
    \begin{block}{c(cc|cccc|c|cccc@{\hspace*{5pt}})}
    p_1         &1&0& \BAmulticolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{$B_1$}}& 0 &...&1&...&1\\
    p_2         &0&1& &&&&0&...&0&...&1\\
    p_3         &0&0& &&&&0&...&1&...&1\\
    p_4         &0&0& &&&&0&...&0&...&1\\
    \cline{1-12}% don't use \hline
    p_5 &0&0& \BAmulticolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{$B_2$}}& 0 &...&0&...&1\\
    p_6         &0&0    &&&&&0&...&0&...        &1\\
    ...                 &...&...        &&&&&...&...&...&...    &...\\
    p_{n-1}     &0&0    &&&&&0&...&0&...        &1\\
    p_n         &0&0    &&&&&1&...&0&...        &1\\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}}_{7\times 8 \text{ matrix}}.
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is slightly misleading to have the underbrace under the explanation borders because the matrix is just the thing inside the brackets. How to get it only under the brackets (not having the $p_1,p_2, ...,p_n$ column)?