# LaTeX Error: File `kbordermatrix.sty' not found

Tags: errors, packages, matrices, sharelatex, overleaf

I have the code for a [transition matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) that compiles fine with a desktop editor like TeXstudio, however fails to compile in cloud-based LaTeX editors like ShareLaTeX or Overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{test}
\author{me}
\date{June 2015}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\kbordermatrix{
    & S_1 & S_2    & S_3    & S_4 \\
S_1 & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
S_2 & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
S_3 & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
S_4 & a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

ShareLaTeX fails to compile this document and reports the error `LaTeX Error: File 'kbordermatrix.sty' not found`. Click here to see for yourself:

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/55777d19fb8b79874d8f1694

Why does TeXstudio have no problem compiling this code, while Overleaf & ShareLaTeX fail to compile the very same code?

The strange thing is, I get this error even though I have loaded the `kbordermatrix` package with the command `\usepackage{kbordermatrix}`. What can I add to my code to make this compile? (Preferably, since this is cloud-based, I would rather simply add some code to my document instead of uploading a file.)

Thank you for your help!

---

*Edit*: For reference, here are some other tex.SE answers regarding `kbordermatrix`:

[Array with labeling columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30791/array-with-labeling-columns/32748#32748)

[Labeling the columns of matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146427/labeling-the-columns-of-matrices/162204#162204)

[Matrix with rows and columns labeled](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223501/matrix-with-rows-and-columns-labeled/223506#223506)

[Where is the \matrix command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/where-is-the-matrix-command/26447#26447)

Comment: Where did you get `kbordermatrix.sty` from? If you need that package, you'll have to upload it as it is not part of TeX Live. That message means what it says: it can't find the file.

Comment: I think you need to download the [kbordermatrix](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kbordermatrix?lang=en) package.

Comment: Aha, do cloud editors like Overleaf and ShareLaTeX only have access to TeX Live packages? If so, then that might explain why it doesn't recognize `\usepackage{kbordermatrix}`. But it's still strange that my MiKTeX/TeXstudio setup can compile the same exact code without any error...

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Overleaf and ShareLaTeX, like everybody, must be careful about software licenses. The license of `kbordermatrix.sty` (lack of licensing information, to be precise) allows it to be on CTAN, but not in free software distributions. Both Overleaf and ShareLaTeX rely on TeX Live, that cannot include `kbordermatrix.sty`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Online LaTeX document sources does not fall within the scope of TeX-SX

Comment: Note that if you are on archlinux, you can get it here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texlive-kbordermatrix/