# how to add caption above and alongside on Matrix

Tags: tikz-matrix

can you help me with printing Matrix like picture below? I have no idea how to add the text above and alongside to Matrix in that way, and how to add those ellipses somewhere especially for sparse matrix? much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: This question already has answers here:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423621/matrix-with-column-and-row-headings

Answer (score 1):

The following example based on the `kbordermatrix` package might serve as a point to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\begin{document}

\[
  \kbordermatrix{
          & (2,2) & (2,3) & (2,4) \\
    (2,2) & a_1   & a_2   & 0     & \cdots & 0 & a_3 & a_4 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
    (2,3) & a_5   & 0     & a_6   & \cdots & 0 & a_7 & 0 & a_8 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0  \\
          & \\
          &\\
          &\\
          &\vdots         &       & & & & \ddots & & & & & & \vdots \\
          & \\
          &\cdots         &       & & & & \cdots & & & & & & \cdots \\
  }
\]

\end{document}
```